# android: disable action bar home button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

We have a file manager-like application where we use the action bar home button as a "go up in the folder structure" action. If the user is at the top of the folder structure, the button should be disabled.

We set the home button as up when the user is within a sub folder. Shen we reach the top folder, we disable showing as up.

```
    // Update home
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(hasParent);
```

the problem is that the button is still "enabled" in that the user can press it can see visual feedback that is was pressed. we want the action bar home button to be completely disabled in this case, when there is no parent folder.

I tried calling `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled()`, but does not disable the button but in stead  this removes the home button completely.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did you try `setHomeButtonEnabled()`? That is new to API Level 14, so you would have to skip it for Honeycomb tablets.

Comment: This method also exists for both `ActionBarSherlock` and `ActionBarCompat` classes

Comment: Not sure why this method does not work for me. The button can still be clicked with visual effect. The API is kit kat 4.4.4 - Really confused, much trouble with Android (a product of open source programmers - I've never or really rarely encountered the same annoying thing when working with .NET).